# Hibernate custom foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to use a database where 2 tables of some custom foreign key. It will reference one field under certain condition and another field otherwise.

How do I annotate this using Hibernate ?

Here are the tables.

```
---------------------------                      ---------------------------
|         customer        |                      |         address         |
---------------------------                      ---------------------------
| - id                    |                      | - address_code          |
| address_code            |                      | - customer_id           |
| primary_language_code   |                      | - language_code         |
| secondary_language_code |                      | ...                     |
| ...                     |                      |                         |
---------------------------                      ---------------------------
```

Fields beginning with `-` are (part of) primary key.
Foreign key is as follow :

```sql
customer join address on 
    (customer.id = address.customer_id
    and customer.address_code = address.address_code
    and (case when customer.primary_language_code <= 2 
              then customer.primary_language_code 
              else customer.secondary_language_code
         end) = address.COD_LAN)
```

Here are the models :

```
@Getter              \
@Setter              |   //lombok
@NoArgsConstructor   /
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="primary_language_code")
    private int primaryLanguageCode;

    @Column(name="secondary_language_code")
    private int secondaryLanguageCode;

    ?
    private Address address;
}

@Getter              \
@Setter              |   //lombok
@NoArgsConstructor   /
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressId id;
}

@Getter              \
@Setter              |   //lombok
@NoArgsConstructor   /
@Embeddable
public class AddressId implements Serializable, Comparable<AddressId> {

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private int customerId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "address_code")
    private String addressCode;

    ?
    private int languageCode;
}
```

Edit :

- I tried using a calculated field and map from this field. Problem : how can I map this calculated field ?
- I tried using @Where clause but model field name is concatenated to sql query field `customer0_.address_primary_language_code` :

```java
@Where(clause = "(customer.primary_language_code <= 2 then customer.primary_language_code else customer.secondary_language_code end) = address.COD_LAN)")
```

- I tried several other things without much success either.

Comment: you should use annotation oneToOne mapping in this case. Sample Example https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Comment: Also addressCode should be used to joinColoumn

Comment: My problem here is not how to use a simple one to one mapping. My problem is that a column will map column `primary_language_code` or `secondary_language_code` depending on a condition. How can I write this condition ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to load it as it is and manage the condition in Model object.

Comment: That's the workaround I'm currently doing as don't find the solution to my question. I'm not feeling good about this however as the code I'm changing (the models) is used by several other applications :/

Comment: @Formula annotation might be used in your case, have you tried that ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found some creepy hack using sql injection that solves my problem but can be prone to bugs in some conditions.

If join was only on `primary_language`, code would be like this :

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id"),
              @JoinColumn(name = "primary_language_code", referencedColumnName = "language_code"),
              @JoinColumn(name = "address_code", referencedColumnName = "address_code")})
private Address address;
```

```java
@Column(name = "language_code", nullable = false)
private int languageCode;
```

Hibernate will generate a query like this :

```sql
select customer0_.id as ...,
       customer0_.primary_language_code as ...,
       customer0_.secondary_language_code as ...,
       customer0_.address_code as ...
```

The idea is to change the name value to inject sql code :

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id"),
              @JoinColumn(name = "id, case when customer.primary_language_code <= 2 " +
                                          "then customer.primary_language_code " +
                                          "else customer.secondary_language_code end",
                          referencedColumnName = "language_code"),
              @JoinColumn(name = "address_code", referencedColumnName = "address_code")})
private Address address;
```

Generated sql query will look like this :

```sql
select customer0_.id as ...,
       customer0_.primary_language_code as ...,
       customer0_.secondary_language_code as ...,
       customer0_.id,                                    <--- sql injection here
       case
           when customer.primary_language_code <= 2 then customer.primary_language_code 
           else customer.secondary_language_code 
       end as ...,
       customer0_.address_code as ...
```

This will work unless you have primary_language or secondary_language in another table you need to join on the customer table.

I'd be glad to find a better solution to this question as I don't really dare to use it in production.